# Minimize, Maximize and Close Button in title bar. How can we remove this and put back the window options?

Tags: titlebar, button, minimize

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I ran in to a small trouble, and I do not know how to overcome this. I am attaching the pic for better comprehension.
[image]

The minimize, maximize and close shifted to title bar. And normal windows does not have any of those buttons. How can I revert the changes. I do not know if any extension is causing this, I searched all extensions for words "minimize", "maximize", and "close" but there is no extension matches. If anyone can help to saying what is wrong in this or how can I correct this, it would be a great help. Thanks . :)

Comment: A quick way to get rid of the issue would be to disable all extensions and enable them one by one.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/G2KnKtcN/Screenshot-from-2021-01-11-17-13-49.png Thank you friend. This is established now that one of the extensions is causing this thing. Will post which one exactly after testing each extension. :)

Comment: Before I could test every extension, I would like to notify a strange issue. When all extensions are off, the ribbon (max,min,close) does appear in all windows and looks like this https://i.postimg.cc/tRWtJcqs/Screenshot-from-2021-01-11-17-36-00.png      When I click the maximise button the screen looks like this https://i.postimg.cc/pdKXzKpJ/Screenshot-from-2021-01-11-17-36-14.png It is not taking all the space and fully expanding!! (This phenomenon only happening in Gnome Tweaks) My gnome-shell --version is 3.36.7 and gnome-tweaks --version is 3.34.0.

Comment: The extension that is causing this is named as Unite. I have kept these settings now and it shows the ribbon (min, max, close) : https://i.postimg.cc/9Xgw8yYY/Screenshot-from-2021-01-11-18-23-53.png    and https://i.postimg.cc/JzY1mQtp/Screenshot-from-2021-01-11-18-24-00.png

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 21.04 (Gnome v3.38.4), I first added [Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/) and then [Unite](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1287/unite/) and faced a similar issue.

By first removing Unite and then Pixel Saver from Extensions, I was able to get rid of the buttons in the panel.

To install/re-install pixel saver with no maximize, minimize and close buttons in the panel, follow the solution given by [user paime in Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/):

> Whether the close/minimize/maximize buttons do show or not is quite
> random. Personally, I just don't want it at all. For record, I get rid
> of them by commenting the 4 lines with occurrences of "Button" in
> ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixel-saver@deadalnix.me/extension.js
> . Then close windows and reload GNOME.
>
> Apart from that, great extension thanks